# How to call function with parameter in view to Force Download in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, web

I want to call function download when I click the Download Text, but my href always showing php error. I got stuck here and confuse how to do it.

This is my view :

```
<?php $i=1; foreach($map as $dokumen)
{
?>
    <tr>
    <th scope="row"><?php echo $i?></th>
    <td><?php echo $dokumen?></td>
    <td><?php $path = 'file/dokumenkp/' . $dokumen;?>
    <a href="<?php echo base_url(). 'dokumenkp/downloadfiles' . $path['path']; ?>">Download</a>
    </td>
    </tr>
<?php $i++?>
<?php
}?>
```

And this is my function in Controller :

```
public function downloadfiles($path)
{
    force_download($path, NULL);
}
```

Comment: it is showing an error, yet you don't provide the error. please provide it, we aren't mind readers.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below example And provide full path using `getcwd()`

```
public function downloadfiles($path){

            $name = 'YourFileName';
            $path = getcwd().$path;
            $mime = get_mime_by_extension(getcwd().$path);
            header('Pragma: public');     // required
            header('Expires: 0');         // no cache
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
            header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate ('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime ($path)).' GMT');
            header('Cache-Control: private',false);
            header('Content-Type: '.$mime);  // Add the mime type from Code igniter.
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($name).'"');  
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
            header('Content-Length: '.filesize($path)); // provide file size
            header('Connection: close');
            readfile($path); // push it out
            exit();
}
```

Comment: getcwd() is to get current directory right?, but i already defined my path that is will repeat and change. I dont understand what you mean, i tried apply and still error

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me there are a couple syntax errors. The main one is in these lines.

```
<td><?php $path = 'file/dokumenkp/' . $dokumen;?>
<a href="<?php echo base_url(). 'dokumenkp/downloadfiles' . $path['path']; ?>">Download</a>
```

In the first line, `$path` is defined and is a string, but in the second line it is treated as an array ie. `$path['path']`. That's going to produce an error.

But there is still a problem if, in the second line, `$path` is used as the string it is, i.e.

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(). 'dokumenkp/downloadfiles' . $path; ?>">Download</a>
```

The problem is the lack of a directory separator between `'dokumenkp/downloadfiles'` and `$path`.

Here is code that fixes all the issues. It is also refactored a little bit to be, IMHO, a little cleaner. (Note how you can use "pre-incrementing" on the counter `$i` before it is echoed.)

```
<?php 
$i=0; 
foreach($map as $dokumen)
{
    $path = 'file/dokumenkp/' . $dokumen;
?>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row"><?php echo ++$i; ?></th>
        <td><?php echo $dokumen; ?></td>
        <td><a href="<?php echo base_url('dokumenkp/downloadfiles/' . $path); ?>">Download</a></td>
    </tr>
    <?php 
} ?>
```

When you get to the controller method `downloadfiles($path)` several things have to be accomplished to make `$path` be what you need.

The first problem is that `$path` is a string with a series of '/' characters in it. CodeIgniter is going to interpret each item after a slash as another argument to the function. In other words, each slash-separated segment of `$path` will become another variable. There are a couple of ways to deal with this fact.

This problem would not exist if we sent only the file's name - e.g. `downloadfiles('Pedoman.pdf')` - where the path could be prepended to the file name. But that would require that all downloads come from the same folder. Your requirement is for different download source folders so we will have to convert `$path` back into a useful string.

That's not very hard to do, but the parts of the framework we will use don't really require that any input parameters be defined for the function `downloadfiles()`. So we won't even though we will still send some.

The next issue is that the `force_download()` function requires an absolute path (full path from the root of the drive). Assuming that the folder "file" is at the same level as "application" we can use `FCPATH` as the starting place.  (`FCPATH` is the full path to the folder where CodeIgniter's `index.php` is found.)

Here's a version of `downloadfiles()` that accomplishes all those tasks - and a little more.

```
public function downloadfiles()
{
    // get the array of the URI segments after the controller/method parts
    $segs = array_slice($this->uri->segments, 2);
    // turn that array into an "absolute path" string 
    $fullpath = FCPATH . implode("/", $segs);

    // add a check to see if that path/file exists
    if( ! file_exists($fullpath)){
        echo "File $fullpath not found";
        return;
    }

    force_download($fullpath, NULL);
}
```

Let me know how this works.

Comment: "<a href="<?php echo base_url(). 'dokumenkp/downloadfiles' . $path; ?>">Download</a>", this cause wrong call function and showing blank page. The $path is to defined parameter on function.

Comment: It's not going to the wrong function. The page is blank because the parameter needs to be converted to a file path so `force_download` can find the file. If it cannot find the file it silently quits leaving you with a blank page. See revised answer.

Comment: My variable path is "file/dokumenkp/Pedoman.pdf" its right on 'view' but in the controller was problem, parameter just read file,  after slash symbol is missing. '/dokumenkp/Pedoman.pdf' is missing. Any help?

Comment: But it's not a "full path", and it needs to be. A full path starts at the root of the drive. On a Windows machine that might be `C:` and on Linux, it would likely be `/var`. The problem is that CI is separating each item in the path as a separate argument everytime it sees a '/'.